# How to connect to VPN while in aeroplane mode?

Tags: vpn

When I put my phone  (running Android 6) in aeroplane mode and switch on Wi-Fi the VPN option in settings is greyed out (i.e. not enabled), preventing me from connecting to a VPN. Is there any way to overcome this without turning aeroplane mode off?

Alternatively, if I sign up to one of the VPN services that have their own apps, would they connect to the provider's VPN while the phone is in aeroplane mode?

Comment: Yes I reckon its possible to do that

Comment: The only tunnel solution I know that does this is Shadowsocks, since it uses a no-connection mechanism.